# when negotiateServiceCredential set to false WCF client gets: An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, wcf-client, wshttpbinding

I built a WCF service that uses wsHttpBinding and a client that invokes it.

But I still getting the following error message:

```
An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.
```

and the inner exception is:

```
An error occurred when processing the security tokens in the message.
```

here is the config file of the service:

```
   <configuration>
     <system.serviceModel>
       <bindings>
         <wsHttpBinding>
           <binding name="myWsBinding">
             <security>
               <message negotiateServiceCredential="false" algorithmSuite="Basic128"
                 establishSecurityContext="false" />
             </security>
           </binding>
         </wsHttpBinding>
       </bindings>
       <services>
         <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="HelloWorldService.HelloService">
           <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myWsBinding"
             contract="HelloWorldService.IHelloService">
             <identity>
               <servicePrincipalName value="host/MAGBAREYA"/>
             </identity>
           </endpoint>
           <host>
             <baseAddresses>
               <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8999/myService" />
             </baseAddresses>
           </host>
         </service>
       </services>
       <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
      </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

and here is the client config file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IHelloService">
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="false"
                            algorithmSuite="Basic128" establishSecurityContext="false" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8999/myService" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IHelloService" contract="ServiceReference1.IHelloService"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IHelloService">
                <identity>
                    <servicePrincipalName value="host/MAGBAREYA"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The problematic configuration is: negotiateServiceCredential="false".

if I set it to true in both service and client the client will work perfectly.(with the above configuration files as they are except of this change)

can anyone tell what do I miss here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The following link should explain it in detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messagesecurityoverhttp.negotiateservicecredential.aspx

Comment: turn on wcf trace on the server to get detailed error

Answer (score 0):

I would try to enable more logging. On your server, you can enable logging of the entire WCF messages in the config file of the service like this to get you started:

```
 <system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
    <listeners>
             <add name="messages"
             type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="c:\logs\messages.svclog" />
      </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>

<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
<messageLogging 
     logEntireMessage="true" 
     logMalformedMessages="false"
     logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
     logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
     maxMessagesToLog="3000"
     maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
  </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

After doing this, you can test the client again to recreate the exception and inspect your .svclog file using the tool **svctraceviewer**